# Is any bounded open set which is of class $C^1$ automatically a uniform Lipschitz domain?

Tags: differential-geometry, partial-differential-equations

Is any bounded open set which is of class $C^1$ automatically a uniform Lipschitz domain?

This question is motivated from here:
[Relation between sets of class $C^1$ and uniformly Lipschitz open sets.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4886632/relation-between-sets-of-class-c1-and-uniformly-lipschitz-open-sets)

It seems that this notions do have plenty of different definitions but at the end they should match our intuition i think, so they should be equivalent and $C^1$ should imply Lipschitz.

Comment: Did you try to prove it?